# Visualização Automatica de uma row selecionada

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tenho uma planilha onde posso carregar inúmeros registros, e tenho também um campo para procurar um qualquer registro. 
Quando eu procuro um determinado registro e o sistema encontra essa `ROW` ela é automaticamente selecionada!

Atualmente, quando eu procuro o registro e o sistema seleciona a `ROW`eu preciso manualmente rolar o scrollbar até a `ROW` selecionada !

Gostaria que assim que uma `ROW` fosse selecionada a planilha pulasse para onde está esse determinado registro que foi selecionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você só precisa dar um `focus` na gridview, é isso ?

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu `datagridview` estiver utilizando um [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx), você pode usar o `index` do `row` encontrado por sua pesquisa na propriedade [**Position**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.position(v=vs.110).aspx). *(Adicione essa linha após encontrar o registro)*

Automaticamente o foco será movido para a linha encontrada mesmo se precisar usar o scrollbar.

```
produtosBindingSource.Position = index;
```